# C programming printf("%d", 50.2);

Tags: c, floating-point, int, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", 50.2);
    return 0;
}
```

~  When I execute it.

[image]

Binary of 50.2 is  ( 0100 0010 0100 1000 1100 1100 1100 1101 ).

So, I expected 1,112,067,277, but, the values are not, nor fixed.

The values are changed every time, Why?

Comment: check your code

Comment: You need to compile with `gcc -Wall -g yoursource.c -o yourprog` (all warnings & debug info), improve the code to get no warnings, then run `./yourprog` and debug it with `gdb ./yourprog`

Comment: Please do not post screenshots for plain text output. Just copy&paste text into your question.

Comment: [don't put screenshots of text output, code or error](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714). Copy and paste here instead

Comment: You might want to look up what the word "undefined" like in "undefined behaviour" means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the wrong format specifier in printf, `%d` instead of `%f`. This invokes undefined behavior.

Whenever you invoke undefined behavior, there cannot be any deterministic or expected output. When you have undefined behavior, the compiler can go ahead and make strange assumptions such as "this float literal is never used so there's no need to allocate memory for it". Meaning you might end up printing garbage memory locations or even having your program crash. So analysing why undefined behavior gave a certain result isn't a meaningful task.

To guarantee deterministic behavior, you would have to do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
  const double number = 50.2;
  union
  {
    double  d;
    uint8_t u8 [sizeof(double)];
  } u = { number };

  printf("Binary representation of %f:\n", number);
  for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof(double); i++)
  {
    printf("%.2" PRIx8 " ", u.u8[i]);
  }
  printf("\n\n");
  printf("Integer (nonsense) representation of %f:\n", number);
  int i;
  memcpy(&i, u.u8, sizeof(int));
  printf("%d", i);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Binary representation of 50.200000:
9a 99 99 99 99 19 49 40

Integer (nonsense) representation of 50.200000:
-1717986918
```

This was on a machine where double was 8 bytes and integer 4 bytes/little endian, meaning you'd get the 4 least significant bytes as some nonsense output (namely the number 9999999Ah).

Comment: Isn't writing to one member of a union, and then reading from another, UB as well?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis It is always UB in C++, but not necessarily in C. C allows it as per C11 6.5.2.3/3. See foot note 95: "If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to
store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted
as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type punning’’). This might be a trap representation.".  Meaning it may or may not be UB in C, depending on if the system supports trap representations or not.

Comment: However, a character type (among which we can safely count `uint8_t` given that the compiler is sane) can never have a trap representation. Therefore it is always safe to split up any data type in C into bytes, but not necessarily the other way around.

Comment: But what about an array of unsigned chars (the only type that can never have a trap repesentation)? OK, let's call it "unspecified" instead of "undefined".

Comment: `unsigned char` in not the "_only_ type that can never have a trap representation".  Optional types `(u)int(8,16,32,64)_t`  do not have them either.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis If none of the involved types have trap representations, the result is merely implementation-defined, as in it depends on the representation of the given types: endianess, type size, signedness, floating point format etc. However, you must use a union for such type punning, when going from an array of bytes to a larger type. Because if you don't, code like `*(int*)&my_uint8_array` would cause other problems related to strict aliasing - which can be avoided by using a union.

Comment: @chux Oh right, this is of course guaranteed implicitly since those types are not allowed to have padding bits and must use two's complement.

Comment: @Lundin Is  `(int*)&my_uint8_array` also a problem due to alignment concerns?  A byte aligned `(uint8_t*)` may not be convertible to an `(int*)`.  Or is that redundant with "strict aliasing"?

Comment: @chux Yeah that's true, but the C standard doesn't forbid misaligned pointer conversions, because there are many systems where alignment isn't an issue. If alignment is an issue, there would be UB.

Comment: Pointer aliasing has nothing to do with that, but the relevant part would be the rules for pointer conversions 6.3.2.3, where they mention alignment concerns: "A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 8):

This is because, using wrong argument type for a format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1, `fprintf()`

> `d`,`i`      The `int` argument is converted to signed decimal

which tells that `%d` expects an argument of type `int` and,

> [....] If any argument is
>   not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
>   undefined.

So, you're passing a  `double` (*in general, even a `float` argument also gets promoted to `double`.*) where an `int` is expected.

Comment: @StoryTeller Right, it is a `double` literal, just wanted to imply that in case there's a float variable also, it'll get promoted.

Answer (score 7):

The reason for the seemingly random values is, that on your platform `printf()` expects integer arguments in other registers that float/double arguments. On x86_64 for example *%esi* (int) vs. *%xmm0* (float)

According to the C Standard this is ok, since you invoke undefined behaviour because of the wrong conversion specifier.

Comment: FWIW, your "%esi vs. %xmm0" is for Linux x86_64. In Windows x86_64 it is RCX vs. XMM0. Same problem, different register.